# Evaluate $ \int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\sin(x)dx $ to accuracy 0.001.

Tags: calculus, integration, approximation

Evaluate
$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\sin(x)dx
$$
to accuracy 0.001.

By definition, there exists an N such that for n > N,
$$
\left| \int_0^1 \sqrt{x}\sin(x)dx - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \sqrt{x^{*}_i}\sin(x^{*}_i) \Delta x\right| <0.001.
$$

But from there I do not know how to proceed.  Are there any theories regaurding approximation that would be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @Mohammad Ali Baydoun: ideea, the integral lies between the increasing sequence
$$ \int_0^1  \sqrt{x}\cdot (x - \frac{x^3}{6}) dx, \int_0^1  \sqrt{x}\cdot (x - \frac{x^3}{6}+ \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{7!})\,dx, \ldots $$
and the decreasing sequence 
$$ \int_0^1  \sqrt{x}\cdot x\,  dx, \int_0^1  \sqrt{x}\cdot ( x- \frac{x^3}{6}+ \frac{x^5}{120})\,dx, \ldots $$
These are sequences of rational numbers, easy to evaluate,  that converge to the same limit $\int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \sin x dx$.

Note that the inequalities between $\sin x$ and its odd and even order Taylor approximations are valid for all positive $x$, something that does not follow right away from Leibniz estimate for alternating series with decreasing absolute values of terms. See the picture below: 
[image]

The fifth and the seventh order Taylor approximation already give the correct fourth  decimal :
$$\frac{608527}{1670760} < \int_0^1 \sqrt{x} \sin x dx< \frac{2557}{7020}$$

The approximation on both sides

$$\sqrt{x}\cdot (x - \frac{x^3}{6}+ \frac{x^5}{120} - \frac{x^7}{7!})\le \sqrt{x} \sin x \le \sqrt{x}\cdot (x - \frac{x^3}{6}+ \frac{x^5}{120} )$$ on $[0,1]$ has an error less than $\frac{1}{7!} = \frac{1}{5040}< \frac{1}{5000} = 0.0002$ so the estimates for the integrals are apriori better than $0.0002$ since the interval has length $1$. It turns out that the estimates are better than $0.0001$, as we see from evaluating both of the fractions.

Comment: Nothing more convincing than a pretty graph

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Use the Taylor series expansion of $\sin x$ and do term wise integration.
$$\sqrt{x}\sin x = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k\frac{x^{2k+\frac{3}{2}}}{(2k+1)!}.$$ 
To get the desired accuracy you will need to adjust the number of terms you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

$\text{Hints: }$

$$\sqrt x \sin x = \sqrt x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} = x^{1.5} - \frac{x^{3.5}}{3!} + \frac{x^{5.5}}{5!} - \frac{x^{7.5}}{7!} + \dots$$

$$| \text{error} | \le |\text{First unused term}|$$

$\text{Your integral is then simple to evaluate using }$

$$\int_a^b x^kdx = \left[ \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} \right]_a^b$$

Comment: How could you justify that the error is less than the absolute value of the first unused term?

Comment: @WhiteRice Alternating Series Estimation Theorem. The limit that the series converges to ($L$) lies between the successive partial sums $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ and hence differs from $s_n$ by an amount less than $u_{n+1}$ where $\{u\}$ is the sequence of terms in the series. So, $|L - s_n| < u_{n+1}$, which means that $|\text{error}| < u_{n+1} \implies |\text{error}| < |\text{First unusued term}|$